# Mapbox is not fully showing in viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using mapbox in my application, normal fragment page full mapview showing,but when using viewpager in that fragment, mapview is not showing full in bottom its showing black color in version `8.0.0`, below versions is showing properly.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SMzF.jpg), showing how it looks.

**tabs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/gs_tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/onegray"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/onegray"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabStyle"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/gs_viewPager">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragmenta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
             android:id="@+id/mapView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"
             app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
             app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
             mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="12.973520"
             mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="77.633006"
             mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="5"
             mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
             tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
             tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
             tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
             tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">
     </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note: I don't know whether viewpager is problem or not, without tabs means its showing full map view. Please someone help me.

Comment: Fixed indenting and added spaced between puntuations

Comment: i didn't understand,the same xml working in fragment without using viewpager

Comment: kindly someone help me

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be a little late but when I faced the same problem, I did a little bit of reading and research to find out that the map when displayed through bootstrap Modal, angular, etc. shows default 400px width and will not take the previous container's width as it is not aware of it and hence its a good practice to use map.resize() method inside the map.on('load',function(){}) in the end of it.
While using bootstrap modal

```
     map.on('load', function() {
    // some code before the resize option
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
     map.resize();
     });
      }
```

where my #myModal is the id of the Div that contains my bootstrap modal.
Hope this helps someone who is struggling with the same issue.